# Push changes to new branch

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, branch, git-branch

I'm still slightly confused about branches with git.

I coded all my changes on the `local master` branch, and then realized I'd want to push those changes on a new branch instead of the `remote master` branch. So now I've created a new branch called `dev` on my remote repo on github and updated the branches-list in IntelliJ. It looks like this:

[image: git branches on intellij]

How do I ensure the changes (which I think are currently being done on `local master`, but I haven't committed/pushed them) are pushed on the `remote dev` branch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using IntelliJ's interface (with `Ctrl+K`) to `git add` the files I wanted and to set the message for my `git commit`. After the commit, which happened on my current "`local master`" branch, I just used `git push origin HEAD:dev` and everything worked as expected.

**EDIT**:

Almost a year later, here is an updated answer with the GUI solution!

After you've committed, you can use `Ctrl+Shift+K` to open up the `Push` dialog. Below is an example of a single commit (named `whatever`) on the `add-failure-TE-dataImpl-ftr` local branch, and headed toward the remote branch `newBranch` which we know will be created on your `origin` remote because there is the little `New` box appearing just to the right of its name.

[image]

Before reaching that state, you normal upstream branch would be showed to the right of `origin:`, you can change that by simply left-clicking it and typing in the name of the new branch you want to create!

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout dev
git add <the_changed_files_you_want_to_add>
git commit
git push origin dev
```

In an ideal situation, the above commands should be enough.

`git checkout dev` may fail due to conflicts, which would complain

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    ....
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
```

If so, you could try:

```
# commit the changes on "master"
git add <the_changed_files_you_want_to_add>
git commit

# if there are any changed files left
git stash
# if "git stash" is not run here, DON'T run "git stash pop" in the end

# create the local dev and apply the new commit
git checkout dev
git cherry-pick master

# if there are any conflicts, open and edit the conflicted files and resolve them and then
git add <conflicted_files>
git cherry-pick --continue

# push the local dev to the server
git push origin dev

# restore and clean the local master
git checkout master
# discard the commit whose changes you want to be on "dev"
git reset HEAD^ --hard
# only if "git stash" was run
git stash pop
```

Comment: Why was there a need for ``git checkout dev`` in your answer? (I just answered my own question and was looking back at the other provided answers.)

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation, where I accidentally started making some changes in my local Master branch without committing them and wanted to move them to a new branch without having to manually making those changes again.

In Intellij Idea all I had to do was create a new branch using the Git button at the bottom right corner and all my changes were automatically there, then I just committed the changes and pushed to remote and it successfully created a new remote branch with my changes.

I am not sure if this will work if you already committed your changes to the Master branch, but in that case you can just create a branch from the Master branch and then just reset your local Master branch later perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't committed any files they should stay the same after you do `checkout` for *your newly created remote branch* (especially if those 2 branches are identical). This will create *your local branch* where you can commit as much as you want, but it will be only *locally*. The latest local commits/changes will go the remote branch only when you do `push`.

I am always careful with changing the branches before I have done any commits as it might happen that you could loose the changes that you made, thus take care.